# Change a current css style sheet in to scss in Angular

Tags: angular, sass

I want to change my existing angular project in css style into scss style sheet.
So, I tried,
        **ng set defaults.styleExt scss** 
but it came an error,
        **get/set have been deprecated in favor of the config command**

How can I make my code working? Is it a problem related to versions of angular cli?